# Get maximum stored value from an item in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to get size of a specific attribute either by AWS console UI or CLI? I need to get size (in KB) of an attribute for each item stored in DynamoDB.

Comment: I'm confused -- are you wanting to get the size of an attribute, or its maximum value?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I need maximum stored attribute value.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question to reflect this? It is currently asking for the size (in KB) of an attribute, but you seem to be asking for the maximum value. Are you seeking the equivalent of an SQL MAX() function?

Answer (score 0):

Scan your table and identify your maximum value. If you need to access the maximum value frequently, you should consider indexing your table's contents in an AWS ElasticSearch cluster.